# jQuery/MySQL WHERE something = function

Tags: jquery, mysql

I need your help to edit my script to make it output results WHERE title = function(search)
If I type in: test, it will print out results, that have test as title.

**search.js:**

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

(function() {

window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'search/:search': 'search',
        '*other': 'default'
    },

    index: function() {
        $(document.body).append("");
    },

    search: function(search) {
        $('#result').load('search.php');
    }
});

new App.Router();
Backbone.history.start();

})();
```

**search.php**

```
$query  = "SELECT title FROM media WHERE title=";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on `.load()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Notice you can pass data in to the function to send to the server.

Learn how to access this data on the server by reading up on [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) request variables.

Don't use MySql functions. They have been deprecated.  You should use [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

For security reasons, read up on [Mysqli prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).